# How to know the colormap of the image in matlab with no image processing toolbox?

Tags: matlab, rgb

How is it possible to know if an image is RGB, or Gray scale? (without image processing toolbox, i mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read an image file, try and read its colormap

```
[I xmap] = imread( ... );
```

if xmap is not empty then the image is an indexed-RGB color image.

If `size(I,3)>1` then you have a full RGB image (already in memory)

Otherwise you got yourself a grey-scale image.